# JSF / EL occasional failure to resolve action method

Tags: jsf, el

Environment:

- JSF 2.1.11
- el-api 2.2
- Eclipse Kepler
- Tomcat 7
- Chrome
- IE-11

I have a working xhtml and bean which contains several action methods and work fine.

I added another commandButton:

```
<h:commandButton id="idBtnSave" value="Save" 
action="#{imageMetadataEditProvider.saveLabelWithBox}"></h:commandButton>
```

...and the action method:

```
public void saveLabelWithBox() {
    saveBoundingBox();
    saveImage();
}
```

... then for some inexplicable reason, EL cannot find method `saveLabelWithBox` on the bean.

I did several rounds of renaming the method, rebuilding, undeploying and cleaning the Tomcat environment, redeploy.  That *almost always* failed.

HOWEVER, What seemed to work was simply to move the `saveLabelWithBox(){}` block to elsewhere in the bean.  Suddenly, it worked again, so I gullibly renamed the method to something more meaningful, then it failed again... EL could not find the method.  So I again renamed it and moved it, rebuilt, redeployed, now it works again.

*I'm curious whether others have had such quirky behavior and what you think might cause this, beyond the typical suspects of corrupt Eclipse workspace, or being on a microwave beam path.*

Comment: there's always a reason.

Comment: It rings some bells to me for the times I was with JSF 1.x versions + Eclipse. The behaviour was the one you're describing. Did never happen to me with Kepler + Mojarra 2.x + Tomcat. Anyway, it seems an Eclipse-wtp related problem, just stablish a custom deploy directory in Eclipse for your Tomcat installation and see if the `*.class` file is being replaced when you change it. You also don't specify if you're using Maven or similar packaging tools.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this quirky problem which seemed related to corruption in the environment.  The cure seemed to be to create a new bean with a different name and import all the methods from the formerly unreliable bean.  I also did the usual Eclipse -clean startup, although that seemed to have no effect.  I also removed the Eclipse .metadata and restarted, although that also seemed to have no effect.

Oddly, after building a new replacement bean, it would not load via annotations:
`@ManagedBean 
 @ViewScoped`

...so I was obliged to define the replacement bean in faces-config, and then it would load at page request time.  I think there is still something screwed up in the environment.  But all the methods are now being resolved and it's been working OK for a couple of days.

Your mileage may vary.